# How to edit a data entity in a dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to learn how to use Jetpack Compose. I've got a LazyList of Todo items, and a button I can click to show a dialog. The dialog has a mutableStateOf holding a string, which it passes out onOk, and then the main composable creates a new Todo() and updates the repository. It's working fine. But now I want to edit a todo item when you long press it, and I can't figure out how to pass an existing Todo entity into the dialog and have it update.

Current code looks like this (removed unnecessary code for simplicity - ItemList is my own @Composable)

```
@Composable
fun TodoList
{
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val allTodos by viewModel.todos.observeAsState(mutableListOf()) 

   Column(){
   
     CreateDialog(visible = showDialog,
                  onOK = { str:String -> viewModel.insertTodo(Todo(txt=str);showCreate=false}
                 )
     ItemList(items = list,
              content = { RenderToDo(item = it, items = listOfTodos) },
              onDelete = {it -> viewModel.deleteTodo(it)}
             )
  }
}

@Composable
fun CreateDialog(visible:Boolean = false,
                 onOK:(str:String) -> Unit = {})
{
    var txt by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    if(visible)
    {
        Dialog(..
            )
        )
        {
            TextField(value = txt, onValueChange = { txt= it })
            Button(onClick = {onOK(txt)}) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Now I want to allow the user to long press the todo item and edit it in the dialog. I realise there is no need to pass the actual entity in just for a single text value, but in reality, my todo entity has more than one property which I want to make editable, so it's easier to pass the whole entity into the dialog, rather than have the dialog pass several values out. In the languages I normally use, I'd be looking to do something like

```
ShowDialog(myTodo:Todo)
{
  var temp = myTodo.clone()
  //make changes to temp
  return temp
}
```

but in Jetpack, with a composable, I am really confused about how to pass the item in, and handle state persistence. I tried this

```
@Composable
fun TodoList
{
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val allTodos by viewModel.todos.observeAsState(mutableListOf()) 
    var selectedTodo:Todo?

   Column(){
   
     CreateDialog(visible = showDialog,
                  onOK = { todo:Todo-> viewModel.updateTodo(todo;showCreate=false}
                 )
     ItemList(items = list,
              content = { RenderToDo(item = it, items = listOfTodos) },
              onDelete = {it -> viewModel.deleteTodo(it),
              onSelect = {it -> selectedTodo = it; showDialog = true}
             )
  }
}

@Composable
fun CreateDialog(visible:Boolean = false,
                 todo:Todo? = null,
                 onOK:(str:String) -> Unit = {})
{

    if(visible)
    {
        Dialog(..
            )
        )
        {
            TextField(value = todo.txt, onValueChange = { todo.txt= it })
            Button(onClick = {onOK(txt)}) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }    
                }    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

But no change happens in the textfield. I am assuming it's because I need a mutableStateOf or something, but I'm so lost I don't even know what to Google!

Could anyone advise on how I should pass an object into the dialog and return a an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mutable state and callbacks like this:

```
@Composable
fun TodoList() {
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val allTodos by viewModel.todos.observeAsState(mutableListOf())
    var selectedTodo by remember { mutableStateOf<Todo?>(null) }

    Column {
        CreateDialog(
            visible = showDialog,
            todo = selectedTodo,
            onOK = { updatedTodo -> 
                viewModel.updateTodo(updatedTodo)
                showDialog = false
            },
            onCancel = {
                showDialog = false
            }
        )
        ItemList(
            items = allTodos,
            content = { RenderToDo(item = it, items = listOfTodos) },
            onDelete = { it -> viewModel.deleteTodo(it) },
            onSelect = { it ->
                selectedTodo = it
                showDialog = true
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CreateDialog(
    visible: Boolean = false,
    todo: Todo? = null,
    onOK: (updatedTodo: Todo) -> Unit = {},
    onCancel: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    if (visible && todo != null) {
        Dialog(/* ... */) {
            var updatedTodo by remember { mutableStateOf(todo) }

            TextField(value = updatedTodo.txt, onValueChange = { updatedTodo = updatedTodo.copy(txt = it) })
            Button(onClick = { onOK(updatedTodo) }) {
                Text("Update")
            }
            Button(onClick = onCancel) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `TodoList` use `selectedTodo` state variable to hold the currently selected todo item for editing, and in the `CreateDialog` composable, use a `mutableStateOf` for the `updatedTodo` variable. This reflect the changes made to the todo item.

Comment: Parniyan this is amazing!!! Thank you so much for this reply, I'd been trying to figure it out for so long and this worked perfectly. Sorry I took a while to reply, I didn't have time to try it until today. One thing which still confuses me is... if I add the line 'var updatedTodo by remember { mutableStateOf(todo) }' to the top of the CreateDialog composable which I originally did, then it doesn't work. I can't figure out why the state needs to be declared inside the actual call to Dialog?

Comment: Hi Toby, ur welcome. I think in Compose, the remember function is used to create a remembered value that survives recompositions. When you declare updatedTodo at the top of the CreateDialog composable using remember, it will not pick up the changes made to todo because updatedTodo will only be initialized once and won't update when todo changes.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions...but what I don't understand is why using remember INSIDE the dialog element changes the behaviour? Is it to do with the way recomposition happens? Maybe you should do a tutorial...because I've read so many and this is never explained!